# Ref current is null

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm logging a ref's current when a resize event is called. When the window is resized the ref's current is null.

```js
class Popout extends React.PureComponent {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.popoutRef = React.createRef() // current = null
  }

  isWithinViewPort = () => {
    console.log('popoutRef', this.popoutRef)
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('resize', this.isWithinViewPort)
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('resize', this.isWithinViewPort)
  }

  render() {
    const { id, children, borderColor, style, hidden, pointerLeft, pointerRight } = this.props

    if (hidden) {
      return null
    }

    return (
      <div id={id} className="popout" style={style} ref={this.popoutRef}>
        {children}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

[Here's codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/fast-firefly-oormb) and the code is under `./components/Popout.js` line 46.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's your question?

`ref` only get set if your component is mounted and rendered. Your `render` method has this condition:

```
if (hidden) {
  return null
}
```

This means, if the `Popout` is hidden, there will be no ref.